# PHP change string parsed from email

Tags: php, email

Using a PHP script file to filter emails. Everything is working properly, but it seems that if I were to initiate a conversation between a cell phone (Verizon Wireless) and the SMTP server, Verizon changes the format of outgoing messages.

For example, I need to respond to an email using XXX@vtext.com but Verizon will respond with XXX@vzwpix.com which cannot be responded to. So I created the following code to try and remove and replace the @vzwpix.com but it still isn't sending the mail. I know the code is working however because if I change the `$from` in the `mail` function to XXX@vtext.com the code works and sends the message.

```
//Parse "from"
$from1 = explode ("\nFrom: ", $email);
$from2 = explode ("\n", $from1[1]);

if(strpos ($from2[0], '<') !== false)
{
    $from3 = explode ('<', $from2[0]);
    $from4 = explode ('>', $from3[1]);
    $from = $from4[0];
}
else
{
    $from = $from2[0];
}

if(strpos ($from[1], '@vzwpix.com') !== false) {
    str_replace('@vzwpix.com', '@vtext.com', $from);
}

var_dump( mail( $from, "Hi", "What is the email:"));
```

I am using `var_dump` just for developmental purposes by the way.

I did some research and I think the best way to do this maybe is to explode the XXX@vzwpix.com at the @ symbol, then run a `str_replace('vzwpix.com','vtext.com', $from5);` However, that didn't work and then I thought maybe implode it after running a `str_replace`?

Answer (score 0):

If the bad domains are static, why don't you explode on 'vzwpix' and then implode on 'vtext'?  This should replace each of the bad instances in you address string.

Comment: I'm away from my main computer, but something like $noBadEmail = explode('vzwpix',$email);  $newString = implode('vtext',$noBadEmail);

Comment: Editing your answer to include a full-coded solution to my question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get the result of your str_replace

```
$from_with_vtext=str_replace('@vzwpix.com', '@vtext.com', $from[1]);
```